# Python variable scope issue

Tags: python, variables, scope

**Python script:**

```
def show(name):
    def getName():
        return _name
    def setName(value):
        _name = value
    _name = ''
    print('Input parameter: ', name)
    print('Global variable: ', say_hello)
    print('Change private variable: ', setName(name))
    print('Get private variable: ', getName())
    print('Private variable: ', _name)
    print('Input parameter: ', name)
say_hello = 'hello'
show('Jim')
```

**Output:**

```
Input parameter: Jim
Global variable: hello Change
private variable: None
Get private variable:
Private variable:
Input parameter: Jim
```

Why doesn’t the inner function change the value of `_name`, yet the function `show` can get the value of `say_hello`? I know it's a variable scope problem, but I want to know some detail.

Comment: My python version is Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 21 2011, 11:29:37).

Comment: Thanks for helping me to explain my question! Thanks all of you! :^)

Answer (score 1):

Assignments in functions are assigned in the functions local scope. `setName` assigns `_name` in the local scope in `setName`, the outer `_name` is unaffected.

In Python 2.X, it is possible to assign to the module global scope by using the global statement, but not to an outer local scope.

Python 3.X adds the `nonlocal` statement (see PEP-3104 for details if you are interested). In your example, nonlocal could be used in setName to assign to the outer local scope.

[This blog post](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/) discusses variable scoping in Python with some nice examples and workarounds (see example 5 specifically).

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpful. :^)

Answer (score 0):

`_name` is, in this case, local to the `setName()` function, as every variable name is when assigned to in a function.

Unless you have a `global` statement, or in 3.x, a `nonlocal` statement - which would help you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not moving `show` as a `say_hello` method?

```
class SayHello(unicode):
    _name = u""
    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def set_name(self, value):
        self._name = value

    def show(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(self, self.name)

    name = property(get_name, set_name)

say_hello = SayHello('hello')
say_hello.show('Jim')
```

You should avoid using global variables if not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thank you! It's really helpful to me! :^)